# How could a program obtain the message queue descriptor in the siginfo_t structure returned by sigwaitinfo()

Tags: linux, posix

Im programming on Linux in c. In the siginfo_t, there is si_fd for the file descriptor. I receive a signal from another process and sigwaitinfo returns the info about that signal. I want to get the file descriptor but have no luck.The siginfo_t struct is as:

```
siginfo_t {
               int      si_signo;     /* Signal number */
               int      si_errno;     /* An errno value */
               int      si_code;      /* Signal code */
               int      si_trapno;    /* Trap number that caused
                                         hardware-generated signal
                                         (unused on most architectures) */
               pid_t    si_pid;       /* Sending process ID */
               uid_t    si_uid;       /* Real user ID of sending process */
               int      si_status;    /* Exit value or signal */
               clock_t  si_utime;     /* User time consumed */
               clock_t  si_stime;     /* System time consumed */
               sigval_t si_value;     /* Signal value */
               int      si_int;       /* POSIX.1b signal */
               void    *si_ptr;       /* POSIX.1b signal */
               int      si_overrun;   /* Timer overrun count;
                                         POSIX.1b timers */
               int      si_timerid;   /* Timer ID; POSIX.1b timers */
               void    *si_addr;      /* Memory location which caused fault */
               long     si_band;      /* Band event (was int in
                                         glibc 2.3.2 and earlier) */
               int      si_fd;        /* File descriptor */
               short    si_addr_lsb;  /* Least significant bit of address
                                         (since Linux 2.6.32) */
               void    *si_lower;     /* Lower bound when address violation
                                         occurred (since Linux 3.19) */
               void    *si_upper;     /* Upper bound when address violation
                                         occurred (since Linux 3.19) */
               int      si_pkey;      /* Protection key on PTE that caused
                                         fault (since Linux 4.6) */
               void    *si_call_addr; /* Address of system call instruction
                                         (since Linux 3.5) */
               int      si_syscall;   /* Number of attempted system call
                                         (since Linux 3.5) */
               unsigned int si_arch;  /* Architecture of attempted system call
                                         (since Linux 3.5) */
           }
```

Any help,thanks

Comment: This is a *user-space* definition of the structure `siginfo_t`. How is it related with a *kernel* programming?

Comment: How does `si_fd` relate to any message queue (descriptor) and what kind of message queue are you interested in? How is this related?

Answer (score 0):

From the [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) man page, where the `siginfo_t` structure is described:

> Signals sent for message queue notification (see the description of SIGEV_SIGNAL in mq_notify(3)) fill in si_int/si_ptr, with the sigev_value supplied to mq_notify(3); si_pid, with the process ID of the message sender; and si_uid, with the real user ID of the message sender.

Nothing about `si_fd` there.

It seems to only be populated by `SIGIO`:

> SIGIO/SIGPOLL (the two names are synonyms on Linux) fills in si_band and si_fd. The si_band event is a bit mask containing the same values as are filled in the revents field by poll(2). The si_fd field indicates the file descriptor for which the I/O event occurred; for further details, see the description of F_SETSIG in fcntl(2).